# Load .DLL with applet and use it on client

Tags: java, dll, applet, java-native-interface, jnlp

Can I load `.dll` from server to client within applet, and then call methods of loaded .dll (using JNI) on client side?

Comment: @AVD _No! Read this - What Applets Can and Cannot Do_

 
                                                                     Hmm. ..there written that 

**Unsigned applets cannot perform the following operations:
.....

They cannot load native libraries.**
But **Signed applets do not have the security restrictions that are imposed on unsigned applets**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Certainly.  The applet will need to be digitally signed by the developer, and trusted by the end user (they click 'OK' when prompted).  Put the natives in the root of a Jar and add it to the run-time class-path of the applet, using a reference in the `archive` attribute.

Using the traditional method of deploying natives to an applet using the `archive` attribute has the disadvantage that every client gets the natives for Windows, OS X and *nix.  3 times as many natives as they actually need.

A recent (Java Plug-In 2, introduced in Sun's version 1.6.0_10) ability is to launch embedded applets using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), which then allows us to partition the download of natives for the user.  Each OS will get only the natives it needs.

---

> ..how to declare applet class-path?

It is specified in the [`resources` section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources).

E.G. from docs.

```xml
<resources os="SunOS" arch="sparc">
  <nativelib href="lib/solaris/corelibs.jar"/>
</resources>
```

Any resources section with no `os` or `arch` attribute will be downloaded by all JWS clients, the rest only by those that match.