# Determine the jvm bitness on client machine without running an applet

Tags: javascript, jvm

Is there a way to determine the jvm bitness on the client machine without using applets ? I did see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440160/detect-version-of-java-using-javascript) but this determines the jvm version and not the bitness. Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely not. Why do you need to know this? (I ask because there may be a better way of doing it.)

Comment: I want the user to be able to download a specific version of a dll depending on the jvm bitness.

Comment: What is the DLL for? Keep in mind that the JVM bitness may not match the overall system.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. Yes, I am aware of that. It is the SigUSB.dll. For this particular DLL, the version the user needs depends on the JVM bitness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to determine browser bitness - 32-bit java plugin will not run in 64-bit browser and vise versa.

However, user can have both 32 and 64 bit java. IMHO you should rethink your approach. For example, let user download executable jar file that will download and install DLL you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did reconsider my approach and used applet with jnlp. I added the 64 and 32 bit DLL to two different jars and the applet loads the required DLL based on the JVM bitness. I also referred to  this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154013/load-dll-with-applet-and-use-it-on-client) to help me do this.